# fs.writeFile creates read only file

Tags: node.js, electron, readonly, fs

I am writing an electron application and some times I need to save some text into a file.

I am using the dialog module to let the user choose where to save the file and hot to name the file.
Here is the part of the code that handles the file creation:

```
var exportSettings = (event, settings) => {
        //settings is a css string 
        console.log(settings)
        dialog.showSaveDialog({
            title: 'Export settings as theme',
            filters: [{
                name: 'UGSM theme(CSS)',
                extensions: ['css']
            }]
        },(fileName) => {
            console.log('callback scope');
            console.log(fileName);
            if (fileName) {
                fs.writeFile(fileName, settings, (error) => {
                   console.log(error);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The file is being created after the user selects a directory and a file name.However it is created as read only and I would like it to be created as editable from everyone.Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Do you know if the issue is one of file permissions for the users trying to access the file or because the file is set to read-only for all?  The `fs.writeFile()` function accepts some flags that influence the file.  Have you explored that option?  Many of those flags are documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback

Comment: You should show the exact value of `settings`.

Comment: @mscdex `settings` is a string containing some css code to be written on a file

Comment: I tried to change mode to 0777 but with no luck  @jfriend00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hey finally found the root cause of the problem

The problem lies on how I started my electron app. `

I use `sudo electron .` to start my app since it requires root access to perform some system tasks.Hence files created by `sudo` or `root` are read only to other users.To fix that I used `chmod()` to change permissions of file after it was created.

Here is my solution:

```
var exportSettings = (event, settings) => {
        dialog.showSaveDialog({
            title: 'Export settings as theme',
            filters: [{
                name: 'UGSM theme(CSS)',
                extensions: ['css']
            }]
        }, (fileName) => {
            if (fileName) {
                fs.writeFile(fileName, settings, (error) => {
                    //Since this code executes as root the file being created is read only.
                    //chmod() it
                    fs.chmod(fileName, 0666, (error) => {
                        console.log('Changed file permissions');
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: There is no need for an additional `fs.chmod` call since `fs.writeFile` has an optional `options` argument ([see the docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)): `fs.writeFile(fileName, settings, { mode: 0666 }, next)`.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny i tried that but it didn't work for some reason

Comment: According to node.js docs, `fs.writeFile` sets `0666` mode for newly created files by default, which makes the whole situation even stranger.

Comment: maybe the default mode changes when node run as root

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny try to open a node cli as root.The write a file somewhere using `fs.writeFile` and check its permissions

Comment: Just figured out why `mode` doesn't work in your case. It's caused by linux `umask`. Have a look at the [similar issue on github](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1104) and at [detailed `umask` explanation on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/44542/128944). `chmod` works because it's not affected by `umask`.